# Add 5 seconds to all timestamps in a text file

Tags: python, regex, file, python-datetime

I have a text file that contains information that looks like this:

```
341
00:33:17,72 --> 00:33:24,05
this happen because si se puede
yes we can. Thank you very much.
```

I'm trying to find all instances of time and add five seconds to the time.  This is what I have so far:

```
import re
import string
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import fileinput



fr = open('project.txt')
text = fr.read()
fr.close()
regex = r"(\d+):(\d+):(\d+),(\d+)"
matches = re.finditer(regex, text, re.MULTILINE)

def changeTimes():
    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

        print("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum=matchNum, start=match.start(),
                                                                            end=match.end(), match=match.group()))
        t1 = datetime.strptime(match.group(), "%H:%M:%S,%f")  # put your time instead
        delta = timedelta(seconds=5)  # seconds, minutes, hours, whatever
        t1 += delta
        print(t1.strftime("%H:%M:%S,%f")[:-4])
        with fileinput.FileInput('project.txt', inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
            for line in file:
                print(line.replace(r"(\d+):(\d+):(\d+),(\d+)", t1.strftime("%H:%M:%S,%f")[:-4]), end='')
```

I am calling `changeTimes()` below a slew of comments.

I am getting no errors, and also no change to the text file.  Why is this?

Comment: You never call `changeTimes()`. Also, You probably want to do all the replacements in the `text` variable then write the modified `text` back to the file.

Comment: I'm seeing no errors, but also no change to the text file when I run it.  Why is this happening?

Comment: That is a direct copy/paste from the text file.  It looks like that right now.  So I want it to be :22 --> :29 instead (+5 seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your times are fixed formatting, use `(\b(?:\d\d:){2}\d\d,\d\d\b)` and keep your `fileinput.FileInput` with `inplace=True` (there's no need to pattern match on a separate file read--you can do it all in one loop). Provide `re.sub` with a lambda function that parses, increments and re-formats the matched time strings for each line.

```
import fileinput
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def add_seconds(x, fmt="%H:%M:%S,%f", seconds=5):
    return (datetime.strptime(x, fmt) +
            timedelta(seconds=seconds)).strftime(fmt)

pattern = r"(\b(?:\d\d:){2}\d\d,\d\d\b)"
replacement = lambda x: add_seconds(x.group(0))[:11]

with fileinput.FileInput("project.txt", inplace=True, backup=".bak") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(re.sub(pattern, replacement, line), end="")
```

Output:

```
341
00:33:22,72 --> 00:33:29,05
this happen because si se puede
yes we can. Thank you very much.
```

Comment: works perfectly! thanks a million, I was really beating my head against the wall for way too long.

Comment: No problem--you pretty much had all the pieces together and it was just a matter of rearranging things a bit.